# Some of my Media Queries Work, Other's do not, No Idea Why

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, media-queries, materialize

Like the title states, I have a number of media queries and only some of them work. They all follow the same principal, at a certain screen width hide one thing and replace it with another.

I am using React.js, Redux, React-Materialize and Express.js. Below I have included all 3 relevant files of code, Nav.jsx, SideNav.jsx and the relevant media queries.

Nav.jsx

Note:

Focus on className='sidenav' , className='nav-menu' for what doesn't work
Focus on className='space', id='nav-title1' and id='nav-title2' for what does work

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Navbar, NavItem, Row, Col, Dropdown, Button } from 'react-materialize';
import SideNavv from './SideNav.jsx';

class Nav extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Row>
        <div className='blue darken-2 white-text'>
          <a href="#" id='nav-title1' className="nav-title brand-logo white-text">Late File Tax Return Specialists</a>
          <a href="#" id='nav-title2' className="nav-title brand-logo white-text">Late File Specialists</a>
          <nav left className='blue darken-2 white-text' id='nav'>
            <SideNavv className='sidenav'/>
            <Dropdown className='nav-menu' trigger={
                <Col className='blue white-text nav-menu'>About Our Firm</Col>
              }>
              <NavItem className='blue white-text nav-menu'>###-###-####</NavItem>
              <NavItem className='blue white-text nav-menu'>email</NavItem>
              <NavItem className='blue white-text nav-menu'>address</NavItem>
            </Dropdown>
            <Col className='space'>a</Col>
            <Dropdown className='nav-menu' trigger={
                <Col className='blue white-text nav-menu'>Available Tax Services</Col>
              }>
              <NavItem className='blue white-text nav-menu'>###-###-####</NavItem>
              <NavItem className='blue white-text nav-menu'>email</NavItem>
              <NavItem className='blue white-text nav-menu'>address</NavItem>
            </Dropdown>
            <Col className='space'>a</Col>
            <Dropdown className='nav-menu' trigger={
                <Col className='blue white-text nav-menu'>Business / Individuals</Col>
              }>
              <NavItem className='blue white-text nav-menu'>###-###-####</NavItem>
              <NavItem className='blue white-text nav-menu'>email</NavItem>
              <NavItem className='blue white-text nav-menu'>address</NavItem>
            </Dropdown>
            <Col className='space'>a</Col>
            <Dropdown className='nav-menu' trigger={
                <Col className='blue white-text nav-menu'>Resources</Col>
              }>
              <NavItem className='blue white-text nav-menu'>###-###-####</NavItem>
              <NavItem className='blue white-text nav-menu'>email</NavItem>
              <NavItem className='blue white-text nav-menu'>address</NavItem>
            </Dropdown>
            <Col className='space'>a</Col>
            <Dropdown className='nav-menu' trigger={
                <Col className='blue white-text nav-menu'>Get In Touch With Us</Col>
              }>
              <NavItem className='blue white-text nav-menu'>###-###-####</NavItem>
              <NavItem className='blue white-text nav-menu'>email</NavItem>
              <NavItem className='blue white-text nav-menu'>address</NavItem>
            </Dropdown>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </Row>
    )
  }
}

export default Nav;
```

SideNav.jsx

Note:

Focus on id='open-sidebar' for what doesn't work

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { SideNav, SideNavItem, Button } from 'react-materialize';

class SideNavv extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <SideNav
        trigger={<Button id='open-sidebar' icon='menu'></Button>}
        options={{ closeOnClick: true }}
        >
        <SideNavItem userView
          user={{
            background: 'public/concert.jpg',
            image: 'public/mic.jpg',
            name: 'John Doe',
            email: 'example@gmail.com'
          }}
        />
        <SideNavItem waves href='#!' icon='info_outline'>About Our Firm</SideNavItem>
        <SideNavItem waves href='#!' icon='description'>Available Tax Services</SideNavItem>
        <SideNavItem waves href='#!' icon='perm_identity'>Business / Individuals</SideNavItem>
        <SideNavItem waves href='#!' icon='language'>Resources</SideNavItem>
        <SideNavItem waves href='#!' icon='contacts'>Get In Touch With Us</SideNavItem>
      </SideNav>
    )
  }
}

export default SideNavv;
```

Media Queries

Note: 
@media .space works but even though it is in the same query, .nav-menu does not

@media #nav-title1 and #nav-title2 is a perfect example that works

@media #open-sidebar and .sidenav (which are really the same thing) do not work at all

```
#nav-title1 {
  display: none;
  transition: 300ms;
}
@media (max-width : 799px) {
  #nav-title2 {
    display: none;
    transition: 300ms;
  }

  #nav-title1 {
    display: initial;
    transition: 300ms;
  }
}

.nav-menu, .space {
  display: initial !important;
  transition: 300ms;
}
@media (max-width: 850px) {
  .space, .nav-menu {
    display: none !important;
    transition: 300ms;
  }
}

#open-sidebar, .sidenav {
  visibility: visible;
  transition: 300ms;
}
@media (min-width: 800) {
  #open-sidebar, .sidenav {
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: 300ms;
  }
}
```

Comment: Your last media query is missing the "px" units.

Comment: Thanks, that is a simple thing that I just didn't see. It sorted out the hamburger. So the hamburger will disappear and reappear but the tabs themselves stay constant.

The main thing that confuses me is the .space works perfectly but ,nav-menu does not and they are in the same @media query.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at css code, it seems like last media query doesn't have `"px"` at the end of `800`.

Comment: As mention in the comment on my original post, I did change that but it only solved the hamburger. So the hamburger will disappear and reappear but the tabs themselves stay constant. The main thing that confuses me is the .space works perfectly but ,nav-menu does not and they are in the same @media query.

Comment: Hey, I have compiled this code and reviewed it and It works properly. I think the reason why you are confused is because react-materialize library is creating additional div, that acts as trigger div/btn that your css is not targeting. In other words you are only targeting `.nav-menu, .space` but not the additional markup that react outputs. If you inspect your code you will see this div that comes before nav-menu and it does not have the same classes. `<div data-activates="dropdown_2" class="col dropdown-button">Available Tax Services</div>`

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this comment by Lev,

Hey, I have compiled this code and reviewed it and It works properly. I think the reason why you are confused is because react-materialize library is creating additional div, that acts as trigger div/btn that your css is not targeting. In other words you are only targeting .nav-menu, .space but not the additional markup that react outputs. If you inspect your code you will see this div that comes before nav-menu and it does not have the same classes. Available Tax Services – lev yesterday